# PHP foreach stopped working after some time

Tags: php, foreach, phpmailer

This PHP foreach loop is supposed to loop through all the images that had been just uploaded to a directory from a form and then attach them all to an email and display them in email. It worked when I first made it a couple of months ago but now for some reason it is no longer working.. It will only attach one picture..

```
$files = array();
while ($files[] = readdir($dir2));
closedir($dir2);

foreach ($files as $file) {

    //MANIPULATE FILENAME HERE, YOU HAVE $file...

    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != 'resources' ){
        $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file);
        $url = '../mobile_patrol_reports/'.$id.'/'.$file;
        $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($url, $withoutExt);
        $mail->Body .= '<img src="cid:'.$withoutExt.'">';
        break;
    }

}
```

Maybe it was something to do with adding an SSL cert and I could be missing something?

Comment: The break will terminate execution

Comment: Have a look at `pathinfo()` as well instead of loading a whole regex engine to do something that can be done quite simply without regex.

Comment: Have you added another directory as well as `resources` that you are not checking for?

Comment: When the break is not included it adds the first image twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has something to do with `break;` that you have in your `foreach` loop. The first time the condition in `if` is true, `break` will cause to abort the execution of the `foreach`.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: When the break is not included it adds the first image twice

Comment: Then you must look for an error in the logic. Obviously adding `break` is not the answer here.